# Selecionar a próxima TD dentro de um Loop

Tags: jquery

Como faço para acessar o texto da próxima `td` dentro da iteração do `loop`?

Preciso verificar o texto da proxima `TD`(da próxima TR) depois da `TR` atual do `loop`. 
Na primeira fileira de `td` (administração), ou seja, quero encontrar a próxima TD que tem o texto Administração através do loop mas não consegui com a função `next()`, alguém me ajuda?

```js
    $("tr td:first-child").each(
      function(index) {
       var texto = $(this).closest("tr td").text();
       console.log(texto);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>administração</td>
            <td>teste1</td>
            <td>teste2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>administração</td>
            <td>teste3</td>
            <td>teste4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>administração</td>
            <td>teste5</td>
            <td>teste6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Empresas</td>
            <td>teste7</td>
            <td>teste8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Empresas</td>
            <td>teste9</td>
            <td>teste10</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tem que melhorar essa pergunta, está mal formulada e difícil de entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que vc quer, vc pode usar o `this.next` para pegar o texto da próxima `TD` que vem após a primeira.

Ficaria assim

```js
$("tr td:first-child").each(function(index) {
    var texto = $(this).closest("tr td").text();
    console.log(texto);
    var textoy = $(this).next("td").text();
    console.log(textoy);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>administração</td>
        <td>teste1</td>
        <td>teste2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>administração</td>
        <td>teste3</td>
        <td>teste4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>administração</td>
        <td>teste5</td>
        <td>teste6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Empresas</td>
        <td>teste7</td>
        <td>teste8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Empresas</td>
        <td>teste9</td>
        <td>teste10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Edit**

Eu não manjo muito de jQuery, mas as vezes só com JS pode te ajudar tb.

Esse script vai pegar qq TD que tenha o texto "administração" dentro, vai pegar a próxima TD depois dela, e vai pegar a qq TR depois da TR que não tem td=administração

```js
var oi = document.querySelectorAll('td:first-child');

oi.forEach(el => {
    if(el.textContent == 'administração') {
        el.style.color = 'blue';
        // console.log(el);
        el.nextElementSibling.style.color = 'red';
        // console.log(el.nextElementSibling);
    } else if (el.parentElement) {
        el.parentElement.style.color = 'green';
        console.log(el.parentElement)
    }
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>administração</td>
        <td>teste1</td>
        <td>teste2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>outro nome</td>
        <td>teste1</td>
        <td>teste2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>administração</td>
        <td>teste3</td>
        <td>teste4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>outro nome</td>
        <td>teste1</td>
        <td>teste2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>outro nome</td>
        <td>teste1</td>
        <td>teste2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>administração</td>
        <td>teste3</td>
        <td>teste4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>administração</td>
        <td>teste3</td>
        <td>teste4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>outro nome</td>
        <td>teste1</td>
        <td>teste2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: mas eu não quero pegar o texto da próxima TD que está do lado dela, eu quero pegar o Texto da próxima TD da outra TR, que tem o texto igual ao da TD da TR anterior

Comment: @DemetriusFernandes desculpe amigo, mas não consegui entender o que vc quer

Comment: Eu quero pegar a próximo TD que tenha o Texto igual a "administração", mas fazer isso através do loop, verificando de uma em uma qual é a próximo que tem o texto administração, entendeu ?

Comment: @DemetriusFernandes da uma olhada no Código olha se era isso que vc precisava

Comment: muito obrigado amigo, me ajudou muito ein, salvou meu emprego kkkkk

Comment: @DemetriusFernandes hahaha que bom que ajudou ai, fico feliz por vc! E para não passar apero de novo te sugiro fazer um desses cursos online, mesmo que seja algum free no Youtube, lá tem material bom pra inciante e de graça! Sucesso 

Comment: Eu não sou iniciante não kkkk já mexo com programação faz tempo, só que eu Tava muito fixado no jquery pra resolver o problema e acabei me esquecendo que no javascript puro poderia ser mais fácil kkkkk

Comment: @DemetriusFernandes já eu sou iniciante em JS e tenho dado muita preferencia para JS puro, meu exemplos ainda são meio "grosseiros", não sei refinar o código, mas fica bem simples de ler eu acredito rss

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem, mas fiz isso para lhe ajudar.

```
<script>
    $("tr td:first-child").each(
      function(index) {
          var texto = $(this).closest("tr td").text();
          if(texto == "administração"){
            var td_administracao = $(this);
            console.log(texto);
          }
    })
</script>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>administração</td>
                <td>teste1</td>
                <td>teste2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>administração</td>
                <td>teste3</td>
                <td>teste4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>administração</td>
                <td>teste5</td>
                <td>teste6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Empresas</td>
                <td>teste7</td>
                <td>teste8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Empresas</td>
                <td>teste9</td>
                <td>teste10</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se é exatamente isso, mas aqui você consegue iterar sobre o texto de todas as tds.

```
$.each($('td'), function(k, v){
  if($(v).text() == 'administração'){
    $(this).css('color','blue');
  }
})
```